# Want To Ignore Messages About Gemfile Selection the Ruby Version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, gemfile, rvmrc

I have recently upgraded all of my Rails applications to Rails 4.0.0 Ruby 2.0.0.  I am working on a Mac Mini Server running OS X Server (Mountain Lion).

I have the following statements in my Gemfile.

```
ruby "2.0.0"
#ruby-gemset=mygemsetname
```

When I navigate to the folder of one of my Rails 4 applications the following messages are displayed.

```
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/myusername/sites/myrailsapp/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.
```

I am running RVM 1.21.15 on my development server and RVM 1.22.3 on my production server.  From my understanding rvmrc is deprecated.  I'm not using it in any of my applications.  So running these commands do nothing.

How can I stop these messages from displaying?

Any help would be appreciated.  I will keep searching.

**UPDATE 10/30/2013 8:10 am CDT**

RVM has been updated to check more conditions before issuing these messages.  Doing `rvm get head` to update RVM to the current version should fix the problem.  As of now the current version is 1.23.13.

Comment: Did you try `rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/myusername/sites/myrailsapp/Gemfile`?

Comment: After posting this question I tried doing the ignore command for each gemfile on my development server.  It only ignored the warning messages for one of them.  I'm thinking it should only display if .rvmrc is being used. I quit using it for most of them of my Rails 3 apps long before rewriting them in Rails 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug reported https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2328 - you can "watch it" for solution, the button "Watch" is on bottom.